# permission denied issue when trying to access files in a folder with xlrd or shutil

Tags: python, xlrd, shutil

**Edit: I deleted this but I'm going to undelete because I think it could be useful. And post what was actually happening which I didn't realize at the time.**

Original Question: I'm trying to open a set of excel files where one is currently open by another user. All of the other files work, but this one I get 'permission denied' errors.

Windows gives you the option to "read only" open the file, but I can't seem to find an equivalent in python (xlrd), so I thought I would copy the file to a temp location and open it; but that doesn't work either. In either case, i get:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
```

Is it possible to either:

- open an excel file in read only mode (like windows) in xlrd
- copy a file currently in use by another user

thanks !

Comment: Are you just reading the file?

Comment: I'm trying to count the values in a specific column which column index might change for each file (xlsx), but it fails at the 'open' stage (or copy)

Comment: Could you show the line of code that fails?

Comment: ahh it wasn't the actual files it was i guess these "temp" files prefixed by ~$ that were failing, and then shutil was failing for the same reason. the code is just wbk = xlrd.open_workbook(file_name). if there's a file called old_file.xlsx in the path, then the file that fails was ~$old_file.xlsx  ... will delete this question, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, I the files that were failing were also open by other users, so when I went to access them through windows explorer it seemed natural another user having the file open would cause the permission denied error; however the real issue is that as I was looping through the folder I was attempting to access the temp files created by Excel for the other user who was accessing the file.

So, for a given file "old_file.xlsx" that a user had open, their instance of excel created "~$old_file.xlsx"

How I got around this was:

```
files_to_check = [f for f in os.listdir(PATH) if os.path.isfile(f)]
files_to_check = [f for f in files_to_check if '~' not in f and 'xlsx' in f]
```

basically, just making sure that they're the non-temp, xlsx files that I planned to go through.