# Is there a way to copy or open/read a xlsx file while it is in use by another user using Python (Windows)?

Tags: python, excel, windows, python-2.7

I have searched far and wide, but can't find the right solution. All I want to do is get a sum and count of a column and insert that sum in to another workbook. That works fine when no one is in the source workbook. I can easily open the file by going to the file and clicking read only. I can also still right click > copy, then paste it as well, but can't seem to do either of these with Python while it is in use.

If this is a duplicate, I apologize in advance.

This is simply using the basic open or copy functions.

```
shutil.copy(src, dst) #For the copy procedure

openpyxl.load_workbook(file) #For just the open and read
```

Both of these functions basically produce the similar errors when the file is in use by another user.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "myfile.py", line 14, in <module>
sbwb = openpyxl.load_workbook(sbfile)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 164, in 
load_workbook
archive = _validate_archive(filename)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 118, in 
_validate_archive
archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r', ZIP_DEFLATED)
File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 778, in __init__
self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 
'file location'
```

*UPDATE*
I found the issue and it wasn't related to Python at all. What was happening was that I was searching for the latest file in the folder. When the code searches in the folder, it finds the locked file before the original. I just excluded files that begin with ~$ and it found the correct one and loaded it successfully and that was using openpyxl. Thanks for everyones responses.

Comment: Actually, the dupe target here doesn't feel like an exact duplicate to me. Closer would be [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36201933/permission-denied-issue-when-trying-to-access-files-in-a-folder-with-xlrd-or-shu). (And it has a similar cause and resolution.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to use the library xlrd to open it, here's some code for that:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook

fh = open_workbook((filepath),'r')
no = 1
print ('\n')
for sheet_name in fh.sheet_names():
    print (' Sheet: ',str(no),' |  Name: ',sheet_name)
    no += 1
print ('\n\nWhich sheet would you like to read? Enter it''s number.\n\n')
while True:
    inpstr=input('    > ')
    try:
        (selected_sheet_no)=int(inpstr)
        print (('\n You have selected sheet: '),(selected_sheet_no))
        (selected_sheet_no)-=1
        break
    except:
        print ('\nInvalid input.')
        print ('\nTo go back to start enter "y".')
        continue  
s = fh.sheet_by_index(selected_sheet_no)
for row in range(s.nrows):
    col_value = []
    for col in range(s.ncols):
        value  = (s.cell(row,col).value)
        try : value = str(int(value))
        except : pass
        col_value.append(value)
    data.append(col_value)
```

Unfortunately I am not sure how to open a sheet by name, you will have to refer to xlrd documentation for that. My code gives a list of lists with each sublist being an entire row, each element being a cell in that row.

I am also sorry to tell you I am not sure how to write to an excel file especially if it's already open.

Apparently xlrd can open worksheets already in use, I read that here:

[python library or code to read already open Excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28356985/python-library-or-code-to-read-already-open-excel-file)

Comment: edited just now sorry